# FOP image not found error

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I'm trying to use an external graphic with xslt for PDF generation. Most images are working fine but every now and again one is 'not found' [despite being viewable on a web browser](http://memesvault.com/wp-content/uploads/Derp-Meme-031.jpg). Here's the error that FOP spits out:

```
11:29:15.653 [main] ERROR org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent - Image not found. URI: http://memesvault.com/wp-content/uploads/Derp-Meme-031.jpg. (No context info available)
```

And here's my external-graphic section:

```
<xsl:variable name="mediaUrl">
    <xsl:value-of select="mediaUrl" />
</xsl:variable>
<fo:external-graphic src="url('{$mediaUrl}')"
                     height="200"
                     max-width="200"
                     content-width="scale-to-fit" />
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: it looks like this problem is related to a server not permitting access for the automated request. Is there a way to set the User Agent's URIResolver in fop 2.1? It appears that this functionality existed in prior versions but I can't seem to find a way to do it with 2.1.

Comment: Could it be a server-side issue? With FOP 1.1 the error message says `Error with opening URL 'http://memesvault.com/wp-content/uploads/Derp-Meme-031.jpg': Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://memesvault.com/wp-content/uploads/Derp-Meme-031.jpg`. Maybe the site is configured to refuse requests having / not having specific user agents, to avoid site scraping?

Comment: @lfurini That is very possible - I guess they changed the error code for 2.1. Do you know of a way to set a user agent within fop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the reason why this happened is because, as suggested by lfurini, the server was blocking the request because of the user agent. One can work around this by using a custom URIResolver with FOP:

```
URIResolverAdapter uriResolverAdapter = new URIResolverAdapter(new UserAgentUriResolver());
FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(URI.create("/"), uriResolverAdapter);
fopFactory = builder.build();
```

And here's a very simple URIResolver which adds in the user agent.

```
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.URIResolver;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class UserAgentUriResolver implements URIResolver {

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "whatever";

    @Override
    public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(href);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            return new StreamSource(connection.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. When using this in an Apache Wicket application it still fails for URL's that point to local resources.